# Update every column in every table

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-injection

My database has recently been hacked by SQL injection leaving  tags throughout data in all columns in all tables in my database. Is there a quick way of running a `REPLACE` `UPDATE` on all tables? Something like:

```
UPDATE [all tables] SET [all columns]=REPLACE([all columns], '<script>....</script>', '')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's nothing directly in SQL Server that would allow you to do this.

However, indirectly - there is a way: you could inspect the system catalog views and enumerate all the columns - also limiting those to just (N)VARCHAR/(N)CHAR columns - and you could have your first T-SQL statement generate a list of UPDATE statement from those system catalog views.

With that list of T-SQL statements, you could then run the actual command to clean up your database - this will touch on all the character-oriented columns in all your tables in your database.

```
SELECT
    'UPDATE ' + sch.name + '.' + t.name + ' SET ' + c.name + ' = REPLACE("<script>....</script>", "")'
FROM 
    sys.columns c
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.schemas sch ON t.schema_id = sch.schema_id  
WHERE   
    t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND c.user_type_id IN (167, 175, 231, 239)
```

This will generate a list of `UPDATE` statements as result, and you can then take those statements, copy&paste them into a second SSMS window, and run them to update your columns.

```
UPDATE dbo.T_ServicePSSAAudit SET RunType = REPLACE(RunType, '<script>....</script>', '')
UPDATE dbo.T_PromoStatus SET StatusText = REPLACE(StatusText, '<script>....</script>', '')
UPDATE dbo.T_PromoStatus SET StatusCode = REPLACE(StatusCode, '<script>....</script>', '')
UPDATE dbo.T_DSLSpeed SET CaptionCode = REPLACE(CaptionCode, '<script>....</script>', '')
UPDATE dbo.T_DVPTransfer SET RequestType = REPLACE(RequestType, '<script>....</script>', '')
UPDATE dbo.T_Promo SET Description = REPLACE(Description, '<script>....</script>', '')
```

You can find all the defined system types in the `sys.types` catalog view - I just grabbed the `user_type_id` values for `char`, `nchar`, `varchar` and `nvarchar` here in this sample.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by going through metadata. The `sys.tables` table in your database can give you a list of all your tables:

```
select *
from sys.tables
```

Then you can use the `sys.columns` table to obtain the columns in those tables. And then you would need to generate SQL to make the updates in a loop, for example.

Have a look here for general info on querying the database schema in SQL Server 2005: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345522(v=SQL.90).aspx